# webpack not allowing d3.csv() to load data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack

I have configured webpack the way it is suggested here: https://code.likeagirl.io/how-to-set-up-d3-js-with-webpack-and-babel-7bd3f5e20df7

and when I want to load data via d3.csv there's no result.

here's my code:

```
d3.csv("cities.csv",(error, data) => {dataViz(data)});
function dataViz(incomingData) {
var maxPopulation = d3.max(incomingData, d => parseInt(d.population))
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,maxPopulation]).range([0,460]);
d3.select("svg").attr("style","height: 480px; width: 600px;");

d3.select("svg")
.selectAll("rect")
.data(incomingData)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("width", 50)
.attr("height", d => yScale(parseInt(d.population)))
.attr("x", (d,i) => i * 60)
.attr("y", d => 480 - yScale(parseInt(d.population)))
.style("fill", "#FE9922")
.style("stroke", "#9A8B7A")
.style("stroke-width", "1px")
```

Nota bene, the cities.csv file is in the same folder as my index.js which contains above code.

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: try to debug: `d3.csv("cities.csv",(error, data) => console.log(error, data));`

Comment: firstly it prints:
load
​
bubbles: false
​
cancelBubble: false
​
cancelable: false
​
composed: false
​
currentTarget: null
​
defaultPrevented: false
​
eventPhase: 0
​
explicitOriginalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
isTrusted: true
​
lengthComputable: true
​
loaded: 149
​
originalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
target: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
timeStamp: 1474
​
total: 149
​
type: "load"
​

Comment: and then: undefined

Comment: Which D3 version is this? Also the csv file should be in the same location as your HTML/php file

Comment: it's  "d3": "^4.12.2"

Comment: and all files are in the same location

Comment: Just move `cities.csv`  to  `dist`, check my answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Undefined

> When I want to load data via d3.csv there's no result.

That means that D3 can't find the file so it returns data as undefined 
because is searching inside the output directory: `dist/cities.csv`

You should get some error like this in the browser console:

```
GET XHR
http://localhost:9000/cities.csv
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
```

Just add `cities.csv` inside `dist` to fix the error or check the example below.

### [Output.publicPath](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath)

> The publicPath specifies the public URL address of the output files when referenced in a browser. For loaders that embed  or  tags or reference assets like images, publicPath is used as the href or url() to the file when it's different than their location on disk (as specified by path)

### Webpack.config

Add a public path in the config file:

```
   module.exports = { 
      entry: './src/index.js', 
      output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        publicPath: "/assets/",
        filename: 'index_bundle.js' 
      }
      ...
```

Create the `dist/assets` directory and add the `.csv` file inside.

### Index.js

Add the `publicPath` + the file name:

```
d3.csv("/assets/cities.csv",(error, data) => {dataViz(data)});
```